# Docker and Flutter Web hot reload

Tags: docker, flutter, web, docker-compose, hot-reload

I'm trying to web development environment with Flutter in docker with docker compose.
**I stuck with a hot reload for Flutter, is there any way to make it work? (*except installing VSCode on flutter docker machine*)**

Here is how my `Dockerfile` for flutter looks like:

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app
FROM debian:latest AS dev
WORKDIR /root

# Install flutter dependencies
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y curl git wget unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libstdc++6 libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback lib32stdc++6 python3
RUN apt-get clean

# Clone the flutter repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter

# Set flutter path
# RUN /usr/local/flutter/bin/flutter doctor -v
ENV PATH="/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

# Run flutter doctor
RUN flutter doctor -v
# Enable flutter web
RUN flutter channel master
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web

# Copy files to container and build
WORKDIR /root
COPY . .
RUN flutter build web

# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=dev /root/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  # back-end api built with golang
  golang:
    build: 
      context: golang
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - ./golang:/root
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  # front-end built with react
  flutter:
    build: 
      context: flutter
      target: dev
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./flutter:/root
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: >
            sh -c "flutter pub get && flutter run -d web-server --web-port 3000 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0"

  # postgres is our primary data store
  db:
    build: db
    volumes:
      - ./db/migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrations

  # nginx is used for ssl termination
  nginx:
    build: 
      context: nginx
      target: dev
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - flutter
      - golang
```

*FYI: Project setup is based on the https://github.com/karlkeefer/pngr*

Comment: any progress???

Answer (score 0):

There is a related Issue on the official Flutter Github Repo.
It seems for now there is no way to have hot reload for Flutter Web.

[Link to the Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041)

> Flutter team response: Hot reload on web is tentatively on our [2022 roadmap](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Roadmap) but it's a very difficult problem so no promises.